# Incompatible type class com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult specified as xsi:type.It must be a subclass of 'class com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult

Tags: partner-wsdl, wsc

I'm using SOAP client to do CRUD operations on Salesforce. I'm getting the following issue in query operation . For example get pushTopic list. I have generated stub classes from Partner WSDL version 44 and using it with force-wsc-44.0.0 to make the outbound calls.

```
Incompatible type 'class com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult' specified as xsi:type. It must be a subclass of 'class com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult'
```

Note: This issue happens intermittently.

Please help me find the root cause of the issue.

Thanks in advance.